# Streaming Youtube Videos

Tags: android, youtube, streaming, android-mediaplayer, android-videoview

I am writing an application to play youtube videos using streaming.

First method:

I am getting the RTSP URL to the video using GData APIs.
Here is the code to play the RTSP url.

```
   VideoView mVideoView = new VideoView(this);
   setContentView(mVideoView);
   mVideoView.setVideoURI(Uri.parse("rtsp://rtsp2.youtube.com/CiILENy73wIaGQkDwpjrUxOWQBMYESARFEgGUgZ2aWRlb3MM/0/0/0/video.3gp"));
   mVideoView.start();
```

But it throws error on both G1 device and emulator (Emulator has some
firewall problem as per mailing list)
Here is the error message

ERROR/PlayerDriver(35): Command PLAYER_INIT completed with an error or
info PVMFFailure

Second method:

A hack way to get the path of 3gp file from
http://www.youtube.com/get_video?v=&t=<>&<>..
After getting the file path and I can call setVideoURI and it plays
fine. But it is a hack way to achieve the requirement.
I have checked the Youtube App also, it also does the hack way to play
the youtube url.(Checked with logcat)

I have tried changing from VideoView to MediaPlayer but no change in the error.

Is there a "Clean" way to do this?

Please let me know your thoughts.

Comment: Can't you just invoke the YouTube player to play the video? (similar to how the iPhone YouTube app works?)

Comment: Could you maybe explain the hack a little bit more? I'm facing the same problem.

Comment: Have a look also to [How to get thumbnail of YouTube video link using YouTube API?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2068344/995926) There is a smart answer which points how to get the rtsp url: Try this one as an example: http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/gzDS-Kfd5XQ?v=2&prettyprint=true&alt=json

Comment: if you find the solution, please share it.

Answer (score 2):

If you're willing to do the work in a new activity, the following will work on a device but not on the emulator:

`startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cxLG2wtE7TM")));`

Comment: This works on device because it has youtube app installed. I don't want my application to depend on Youtube App

Comment: is there any other way to play youtube video without youtube app or device doesn't support flash and html5.

Answer (score 2):

Sometimes Uri.parse return "null" because cant parse an rtsp protocol instead of http protocol.

Look it with an Log in logcat `Uri.parse(rtspURL).toString()` and you will see nothing written. or only make `Log.d("tag", Uri.parse);` and the same will be return.

Try to find another way to parse (create) an Uri.

I'd try with that and run:

```
String urlVideo = <your rtspURL>
VideoView video = (VideoView)findViewById(R.id.VideoView01);
Log.d(tag , urlVideo);
video.setVideoURI(Uri.parse(urlVideo));
MediaController mc = new MediaController(this);
video.setMediaController(mc);
video.requestFocus();
video.start();
mc.show();
```

Comment: I'm pretty new to video streaming on Android. Could you flesh out the explanation?

Answer (score 1):

I'm impressed that the dirty way works at all!  If you've got a working solution, go with it.  I don't think there's a clean way to get RTSP streaming working in the SDK yet.

Answer (score 1):

we faced a very similar problem.

At the moment I'm at the first step of my project and I'm trying to make the videoview simply works.
I'm taking data from here: http://gdata.youtube.com/demo/ and I'm testing all the videos links.

RTSP 3GP videos are really really really low quality video.... and there is no way to access to mp4 (good quality) videos. I really don't know how to make it works because I think that MP4 streams are available only to premium devs....

Answer (score 1):

Throw eye over [Youtube API](https://developers.google.com/youtube/android/player/downloads/)

I think this also use youtube app(Which you don't want)

But just refer may be you will find some key to solve it

Answer (score 0):

I've displayed YouTube videos with the following code. I hope its useful, but let me know how it might be improved.

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, 
                  Uri.parse("http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=...")));
}

public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
     // TODO Auto-generated method stub
}
```

Comment: This code will launch default youtube player which is not the requirement in question

Answer (score 0):

The header on the video indicates it does work for Android. So, try a good video link to experiment with. Here is one that I use:

rtsp://184.72.239.149/vod/mp4:BigBuckBunny_115k.mov

I works great on Nexus and Samsung tablets.

Answer (score 0):

do you have the access to the internet?
if not, please add the Internet permission to the manifest file

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

and also please try these URIs:

```
rtsp://184.72.239.149/vod/mp4:BigBuckBunny_175k.mov

http://www.wowza.com/_h264/BigBuckBunny_175k.mov
```