# How to play MP4 videos from Youtube?

Tags: javascript, android, youtube

I need to play videos from Youtube as MP4.

My system (an Android Phone) does not support Flash.

It can play MP4 videos.

So I'm thinking of creating a web page that plays videos from Youtube.

I need to get MP4 videos to play in my page.

What approaches are there?

Comment: [YouTube Terms of Service](http://www.youtube.com/t/terms): "You agree not to access Content through any technology or means other than the video playback pages of the Service itself, the Embeddable Player, or other explicitly authorized means YouTube may designate."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at this related question, where the OP has figured out a hacky way to get the necessary ID and checksum parameters for the get_video "API".
[Streaming Youtube Videos](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1007695/streaming-youtube-videos)

He successfully played back the stream in the VideoView component.
You can use the fmt parameter for choosing which format you want, see wikipedia for a list: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/YouTube#Quality_and_codecs

Good luck.

Answer (score 2):

Did you actually try viewing videos? I have the Droid Eris, which shipped with a YouTube app. Try going to the [mobile version of YouTube](http://m.youtube.com/) and see if that works out.

Google created Android. Google owns YouTube. Transitivity says you shouldn't have any problems.

Comment: Hi, I tried viewing. It is not able to view youtube. My Android stack doesnt support flv. it is optimized stack. I can play mp4.

Comment: Oh. That's way over my head, then. (Deleted my previous comment before I saw you replied, sorry! Was going to sugest an app...but...I doubt that'll help.)

Answer (score 1):

Why not consider using [Mobile youtube interface](http://googlesystem.blogspot.com/2007/06/mobile-youtube.html)

Answer (score 1):

Youtube provides alternative RTSP(real time streaming protocol) links for all existing videos.. dig into youtube api and try to get it.
once you get it you can try code playing the video invoking the inbuilt player to play those videos

Cheers.