# How do I play Youtube videos in an Android custom layout?

Tags: android, video, view, youtube

I have to play Youtube video's in my Android application. I am able to play Youtube videos using the following code:

```
startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cxLG2wtE7TM")));
```

This leaves my application, and starts the mobile youtube where I have no control.

How can I play Youtube videos within my activity? Some blogs suggested to use **HTML5 video** tag to achieve this.

Comment: i think you should search first http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4743416/how-to-play-mp4-videos-from-youtube