# Youtube embed videos not working in webview. What's wrong with this code?

Tags: android, video, youtube, embed, android-webview

I am new to android. I am facing two problems right now  **1**. I  parsed xml file and showed it in webview which contains videos and text . When i click on videos it will not play . In xml videos are youtube embed.

Why is it so?

1.First problem :code and image

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.web_view);
    Intent intent=getIntent();
    String urlsting=intent.getStringExtra("str"); 
    mWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
    mWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    mWebView.getSettings().setPluginState(PluginState.ON);
    mWebView.getSettings().setPluginsEnabled(true);
    mWebView.setInitialScale(100);
    mWebView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
    mWebView.loadDataWithBaseURL(null, urlsting,"text/html", "utf-8", null);
}
```

When i clcik on video it starts browsing and shows only black screen,then nothing will   happen.

![][1]

**2.**  I have you-tube embedded videos url which I given in html tag and try to load it .They are also not working for me. I checked number of questions and blogs and also made no of settings then also unable to show video . Help will be appreciated .Thanks in advance.

```
String video= "<table bgcolor=\"#666666\"><tr><td><iframe width=\"300\" height=\"260\"     frameborder=\"0\" id=\"player\" type=\"text/html\"src=\"http://www.youtube.com/embed/iiLepwjBhZE?enablejsapi=1&origin=example.com\"></iframe></td></tr><tr><td><iframe width=\"300\" height=\"260\" frameborder=\"0\" id=\"player\" type=\"text/html\"src=\"http://www.youtube.com/embed/lBMMTeuJ_UQ?enablejsapi=1&origin=example.com\"></iframe></td></tr><tr><td><iframe width=\"300\" height=\"260\" frameborder=\"0\" id=\"player\" type=\"text/html\"src=\"http://www.youtube.com/embed/BZMkY3y7nM0?enablejsapi=1&origin=example.com\"></iframe></td></tr><tr><td></table>"; 

    mWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
    mWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    mWebView.getSettings().setPluginState(PluginState.ON);
    mWebView.getSettings().setPluginsEnabled(true);
    //mWebView.loadDataWithBaseURL(null,load,"text/html","UTF-8",null);
    mWebView.loadData(video,"text/html","UTF-8");
```

In this case I load the youtube embeded videos to webview but they are also not working.

![][2]

I am using android 2.3.3version.I also want clarification that is there any requirement of install adobe flash player on emulator, but i think no because videos are working in browser. can anybody tell i am right or wrong?? please try to give me solution because i stuck with this problem long ago..

I also tried using object tag as follows:

```
        String obj="<object width=\"300\" height=\"260\"><param name=\"movie\" value=\"http://www.youtube.com/embed/iiLepwjBhZE?enablejsapi=1&origin=example.com\"?version=3&amp;hl=pt_BR&amp;rel=0\"></param><param name=\"allowFullScreen\" value=\"true\"></param><param name=\"allowscriptaccess\" value=\"always\"></param><embed src=\"http://www.youtube.com/embed/iiLepwjBhZE?enablejsapi=1&origin=example.com\" ?version=3&amp;hl=pt_BR&amp;rel=0\" type=\"application/x-shockwave-flash\" width=\"480\" height=\"330\" allowscriptaccess=\"always\" allowfullscreen=\"true\" /></object>";
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6556802/how-to-play-youtube-video-in-android/6556835#6556835 check this once.

Comment: did you have a solution?

Answer (score 8):

You need to

- set a WebChromeClient to your WebView

  ```
      web.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());
  ```
- and turn on hardwareAccelerated value

  ```
  <application
  android:hardwareAccelerated="true"...
  ```

check out http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html and read HTML5 Video support part.

This works for me...

Comment: Holy F!! I have to admit I was 100% pessimistic that this would work, but it just now started to play youtube videos on my Samsung Note 2 in a webview ! wow. P.S. instead of enabling hardware acceleration for the whole app, I enabled it just for the activity that shows the youtube video.

Comment: Unfortunately, when I played the second video I was greeted with an exception in webkit !

Comment: android.view.WindowManager$BadTokenException: Unable to add window -- token null is not valid; is your activity running?
 at android.view.ViewRootImpl.setView(ViewRootImpl.java:798)
 at android.view.WindowManagerGlobal.addView(WindowManagerGlobal.java:288)
 at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:73)
 at android.widget.MediaController.show(MediaController.java:374)
 at android.webkit.HTML5VideoFullScreen.showControllerInFullScreen(HTML5VideoFullScreen.java:425)
 at android.webkit.HTML5VideoViewProxy$VideoPlayer.end(HTML5VideoViewProxy.java:343)

Comment: see the highlighted part: In order to support inline HTML5 video in your application, you need to have hardware acceleration turned on, and set a WebChromeClient. For full screen support, implementations of **onShowCustomView(View, WebChromeClient.CustomViewCallback)** and **onHideCustomView()** are required, getVideoLoadingProgressView() is optional.

Answer (score 2):

I guess, you are using iframe tag in your html code. Change it with object tag. I mean, you must use object instead iframe. An example here:

```
<object width="480" height="330"><param name="movie" 
value="http://www.youtube.com/v/"here is your video id"?version=3&amp;hl=pt_BR&amp;rel=0">   
</param><param name="allowFullScreen" value="true"></param>
<param name="allowscriptaccess" value="always"></param>
<embed src="http://www.youtube.com/v/"here is your video id"?version=3&amp;hl=pt_BR&amp;rel=0" 
type="application/x-shockwave-flash" width="480" height="330" allowscriptaccess="always" allowfullscreen="true" /></object>
```

Use the code below:

```
webview.getSettings().setPluginsEnabled(true);
webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
webview.getSettings().setAllowFileAccess(true);
webview.loadUrl(url);
```

Try this and thick it as accepted if your problem solved :)

Comment: Thanks for reply.It will not working for showing queston mark in place of video????

Comment: I guess you are asking this sentence: "here is your video id" -> it must be like that-> 7wfYIMyS_dI
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7wfYIMyS_dI

Comment: No, I will also try using object tag as you mentioned above then it show ? in place of videos, please check the edited question.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't get what actually you want to say , please explain in brief.Thanks.

Comment: Your link: http://www.youtube.com/embed/iiLepwjBhZE

It must be: http://www.youtube.com/v/iiLepwjBhZE

**Embed will be v. Just v!**

Comment: I try the above change but it will not display video on webview.

Comment: I have changed my answer, added code lines for Android side. Check it. Change yours.

Comment: Do you add html tags? <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"> <head> <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" /> <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" /> </head> <body> **Here is your video object** </body> </html>

Comment: Here is your video object means object tag or only video link.

Comment: Here is your video object means object tag

Comment: I can't help anymore. I used it in my app and it is working. I guess you are missing something. I advise you to check your java and html code again.

Answer (score 2):

have you tested your app in actual device? Because the videos which are embedded like this i.e. iFrame are taking more time to get loaded. In my case, same thing was happening then I changed the webview settings to,

```
getSettings().setPluginsEnabled(true);
```

but after that it was not working on emulator and in device it was loading so I thought its not working but just today I tried the same thing and it was working fine with my surprise. So you just need to add this line of code.

Second thing is that only those videos which are embedded in iframe tag are supported by enabling plugins to true.

Answer (score 1):

This does it:

```
myWebView.getSettings().setPluginState(PluginState.ON);
        myWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        myWebView.getSettings().setAllowFileAccess(true);
        myWebView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());
```

And enable hardware acceleration too!

Answer (score 1):

Follow this source, Youtube video should play

```
        String youtubeId = "iiLepwjBhZE";
        int width = rl.getWidth();
        int height = rl.getHeight();

        WebChromeClient mWebChromeClient = new WebChromeClient(){

            public void onProgressChanged(WebView view, int newProgress) {
                /*
                view.loadUrl("javascript:(function() { " +  
                        "document.querySelector('iframe').setAttribute('style', 'width: 1080px; height: 1920px'); " + 
                        "})()");
                */
            }
        };

        String video= "<table bgcolor=\"#666666\"><tr><td><iframe width=\"" +
                width +
                "\" height=\"" +
                height +
                "\"frameborder=\"0\" id=\"player\" type=\"text/html\"src=\"http://www.youtube.com/embed/" +
                youtubeId +
                "?enablejsapi=1&origin=example.com\"></iframe> </td> </tr><tr><td></table>";
```

//

```
        webView.getSettings().setPluginState(PluginState.ON);
        webView.setWebChromeClient(mWebChromeClient);
        webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webView.getSettings().setAppCacheEnabled(true);
        webView.setInitialScale(1);
        webView.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
        webView.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
        //mWebView.loadDataWithBaseURL(null,load,"text/html","UTF-8",null);
        webView.loadData(video,"text/html","UTF-8");
```