# Play youtube video but not fullscreen

Tags: android

I want to play youtube video, but not fullscreen as i have to write the description below the video. I found many answers but all of them were through intent and take the whole page.

Comment: Are you trying to play it within your own activity?

Comment: yes i am trying it in an activity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the person in this question seemed to get it working [Streaming Youtube Videos](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1007695/streaming-youtube-videos)

However it is somewhat dated. And I don't see many other people who have claimed to have luck getting youtube videos to stream with MediaPlayer / VideoView. It seems like launching the Youtube activity is the preferred way to accomplish it.

Answer (score 0):

Use WebChromeClient (notice CHROME) and a WebView, at least on my tablet that works.